# Using Sample Data saved as XAML, at Design Time in UWP

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I am reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/data-binding/displaying-data-in-the-designer) and trying to use a sample data for ListView to display the data at the design time.
However, I cannot make it, and am seeing an error saying that it cannot build the DataContext in the ListView at the highlighted part below.

`d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData.xaml}"`

Visual Studio 2019 16.9.1

The files are as below. These have been saved in one folder in flat.

Could you help me to know the appropriate way of such using of sample data?

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
    d:DesignWidth="459" d:DesignHeight="262">
    <Grid>
        <ListView d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData.xaml}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Text="-- " />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**SampleData.xaml (marked as DesignData for the build action):**

```
<sample:PersonCollection
    xmlns:sample="using:App1">
    <sample:Person Name="John Doe" Age="20" />
    <sample:Person Name="Jane Doe" Age="30" />
</sample:PersonCollection>
```

**Person.cs:**

```
namespace App1 {
    public class Person  {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Person() {
        }
    }
}
```

**PersonCollection.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace App1{
    public class PersonCollection : ObservableCollection<Person> {
        public PersonCollection(): base(){
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using Sample Data saved as XAML, at Design Time in UWP

I'm afraid you can't use [**Xaml design data**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/displaying-data-in-the-designer#sample-data-from-class-and-design-time-attributes) for UWP app, derive from this document,
***One good option is the Create Sample Data from Class feature in Blend for Visual Studio. You can find that command on one of the buttons at the top of the Data panel.*** Unfortunately,

**The [Data panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/display-data-in-blend?view=vs-2019) in Blend is supported only for projects that target .NET Framework. It's not supported for UWP projects or projects that target .NET Core.**

Comment: Thank you, Nico for your answer. I was thinking it is doable since the article is under the UWP section. But good to have the confirmation even it is not possible. Still I can use the sample data at the design time if I create an object as the sample in the article shows, I am OK with it for now.